# Show that the velocity of the particle is... (Newtons Law question)

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

A particle of mass m is released from rest from height of ten metres above a body of viscous 
fluid. 
Show that the velocity of the particle at the moment of impact with the 
fluid is $14\text{m s}^{-1}$
and estimate the duration of the drop. (Use the approximation $g=10\text{m s}^{-2}$).

So far I have worked out the initial conditions must be 
$x(0)=10, \dot{x}(0)=0$.

With this my motion for all time is $x(t)=-5t^2+10$

where do i go from here?

Comment: I frankly don't see where "fluid dynamics" would be involved. If I understand correctly, it's a simple exercise in kinematics: find the time $ t_0 $ when the particle hits the fluid. What does it mean that it "hits the fluid"? According to your notation, it means that  $x(t_0) = 0$. You have a trivial equation for $ t_0 $, you just need to solve it. For the speed at the moment of impact, it's just $ gt_0 $ (or rather $ -gt_0 $), which is just $ \dot{x}(t_0) $ ($ x $ dot, in case you don't see it).

Comment: The distance from the fluid is 10 metres and the initial velocity is zero, as stated in the question.

Comment: @derpy Whoops, I focused on the number rather than the text. My bad. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the time it takes to fall $10$ meters (when $x(t)=0$) by solving:

$$x(t)=0=-5t^2+10$$ to get $t^2=2$. Thus, it takes $\sqrt{2}$ seconds to fall the $10$ meters. Now plug this into the expression for velocity, $\dot x  = -10 \sqrt{2}$ to get $14 \frac{m}{s}$ at impact.

Hope this helps,

Paul Safier

Comment: Paul, I dont understand, how can velocity be negative and how can $-10\sqrt{2}=14$ ? (sorry in advance for being a noob)

Comment: Because velocity is a vector, i.e. it has a magnitude and direction and the particle is falling down towards the origin (x=0).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints/Solution Outline:**
Set $x(t) = 0$ to find the time at which it hits the viscous fluid.  (This should be $\sqrt{2} \text{s}$.)  This is also called the duration of the drop.

Next, find the velocity equation $\dot{x}(t)$. Now, plug in the time that you found from before, and you should have your answer ($\dot{x}(\sqrt{2})$).